# Inserting tokens after \input

Tags: tex-core, input, external-files

The answer for this should be pretty simple, but I just can't seem to find how to do it. I'm trying to use `\afterassignment` to make syntax for a section header and then use TeX's lexing for `\input` to include that file

```
\def\section#1;{
    \noindent{\bf #1}\par
    \afterassignment\xsection
    \input
}
\def\xsection{
    this text should appear after example.tex's
}
\section SECTION NAME;example
```

This doesn't work because when the assignment happens, the text from `\xsection` appears before `example.tex`'s. I've tried using a macro to switch the two with a mess of `\expandafter`s and `\noexpand`s. What's the cleanest way to accomplish this (with either just primitives or, if necessary, Plain TeX)?

Comment: (TeX's) `\input` doesn't perform an assignment, so `\afterassignment` doesn't work here. You want Knuth TeX or e-TeX?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I'm using pdfTeX, so e-TeX would work fine. I'd prefer to have a way to do it with Knuth's TeX, but I'm not locked in to this method of doing the input, so if I'm not using the right approach, either Knuth's TeX and e-TeX would be sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\input` doesn't perform an assignment, so you have no guarantee of when the `\afterassignment` token will be inserted. With ε-TeX you can use `\everyeof` to add tokens at the end of the input file:

```
% Example file:
\newwrite\temp
\immediate\openout\temp=example.tex
\immediate\write\temp{Some text\par}
\immediate\closeout\temp

\def\section#1;{%
  \noindent{\bf #1}\par
  \everyeof{\xsection}%
  \input
}
\def\xsection{%
  \everyeof{}%
  this text should appear after example.tex's%
}
\section SECTION NAME;example

\bye
```

This code, however, does not handle nested `\section`s neither any `\input` inside the `\section` file (any `\input`) would trigger the `\everyeof` tokens to be inserted. It would be a lot easier if you used like `\section SECTION NAME;{example}`, then the file name would be grabbed as argument and you'd have more control over it.

---

Replying to your comment, yes, delimiting the argument with a space has some pitfalls. If you, as the user of your command, behave, then your space-delimited approach will probably work most of the time. But users don't behave, that's a fact ;-)

For instance, after doing `\def\ample{ample.tex }`, the command `\input ex\ample` would do what you expect, but grabbing that as a space-delimited argument depends on what you input after `\ample`. Another problem is that some TeX distributions (TeXLive and MiKTeX, at least, that I know of) allow you to input a file name with space if you surround the name with quotes, like `\input "example file.tex"` (the implementation also allows you to `\input example" "file.tex` or `\input "e"x"a"m"p"l"e "f"i"l"e"."t"e"x"`, and all input the same file, which is slightly weird). Your space-delimited approach would not accept a quoted file name as well.

If you don't mind a few more lines of code, here's an approach that (as far as I tested) emulates TeX's file name scanner almost<sup>1</sup> completely. I defined a macro `\scanfilename{<code>}<filename>` that scans `<filename>` obeying TeX's file name scanning rules (expanding expandable tokens, stopping at spaces except if between two `"`, and ignoring all `"`), and then runs `<code>`, in which the file name is available as `#1`, so your definition gets a lot easier because you have control after the file name is grabbed. And as a bonus, it works in Knuth TeX :-)

Also, with this one you can nest multiple `\section`s and `\input`.

```
% Example file:
\newwrite\temp
\immediate\openout\temp="example file.tex"
\immediate\write\temp{Some text\par
    \noexpand\section Another section;"another example.tex"\par
    Yet more text\par}
\immediate\closeout\temp
\immediate\openout\temp="another example.tex"
\immediate\write\temp{More text\par}
\immediate\closeout\temp

\catcode`\@=11
\def\@firstoftwo#1#2{#1}
\def\@secondoftwo#1#2{#2}
\def\bool@flip#1{\ifodd#1\chardef#1=0 \else\chardef#1=1 \fi\relax}
\def\bool@false#1{\chardef#1=0\relax}
\def\bool@true#1{\chardef#1=1\relax}
\def\scanfilename#1{%
  \def\filename@action##1{#1}%
  \begingroup
    \def\curfile{}%
    \bool@false\in@quote@bool
    \scan@file@name@peek}
\def\file@name@end{%
    \edef\file@temp{%
  \endgroup
  \noexpand\filename@action{\curfile}}\file@temp}
\def\more@name#1{%
  \edef\space@action##1{%
    \ifodd\in@quote@bool
      \noexpand\add@token{##1}%
    \else \noexpand\file@name@end
    \fi}%
  \if\noexpand"\noexpand#1%
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
    {\bool@flip\in@quote@bool
     \add@token{}}%
    {\if\space\noexpand#1%
       \expandafter\space@action
     \else \expandafter\add@token
     \fi{#1}}}
\def\add@token#1{%
  \toks@\expandafter{\curfile}%
  \edef\curfile{\the\toks@#1}%
  \afterassignment\scan@file@name@peek
  \let\scratch@token= }
\def\scan@file@name@peek{%
  \futurelet\peek@token\scan@file@name@next}
\def\q@nil{\q@nil}
\def\scan@file@name@next{%
  \token@if@expandable\peek@token
    {\expandafter\scan@file@name@peek}
    {\edef\sctratch@token{%
       \noexpand\dissect@meaning
       \meaning\peek@token\space\space\space
       \noexpand\q@nil\noexpand\q@stop}%
     \sctratch@token}}
\def\token@if@expandable#1{%
  \expandafter\ifx\noexpand#1#1%
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \else \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \fi}
\def\dissect@meaning#1 #2 #3 #4#5\q@stop{%
  \pm@strcmp{#2}{}{\unexp@end@name}{}%
  \pm@strcmp{#2}{letter}{\add@char@token{#3}}{}%
  \pm@strcmp{#2}{character}{\add@char@token{#3}}{}%
  \pm@strcmp{#2}{space}{\add@char@token{ }}{}%
  \pm@strcmp{#3}{character}{\add@char@token{#4}}{}%
  \wrong@char}
\def\wrong@char{\errmessage{Wrong character in file name...}}
\def\unexp@end@name#1\wrong@char{\file@name@end}
\def\add@char@token#1#2\wrong@char{\more@name{#1}}
\def\pm@detokenize#1#2{\def#1{#2}%
  \edef#1{\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning#1}}
\def\strip@prefix#1>{}
\def\pm@strcmp#1#2{%
  {\pm@detokenize\tmpa{#1}%
   \pm@detokenize\tmpb{#2}%
   \expandafter}%
  \ifx\tmpa\tmpb
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi}
\catcode`\@=12

\def\section#1;{%
  \noindent{\bf #1}\par
  \scanfilename{%
    \input "##1"\expandafter\relax
  \xsection}%
}
\def\xsection{this text should appear after example.tex's}

\section SECTION NAME;"example file.tex"

\bye
```

(the code was originally written with `expl3`, so it was a lot shorter; ε-TeX makes life a lot easier ;-)

---

<sup>[1]</sup> TeX knows about line endings, so:

```
\input "example
file.tex"
```

will input `example.tex` and then typeset `file.tex"`, whereas:

```
\scanfilename{\input"#1" }"example
file.tex"
```

will input `example file.tex` because the `\endlinechar` becomes a space.

Comment: This works well, but I've now realized that the type of parsing I was looking for was whitespace (i.e. it will work with a linebreak or a space, etc). `\def\section#1;#2 ` works well enough for my purposes, but I don't know if it will break on any corner cases.

Comment: @HoldenRohrer Yes, your space-delimited approach has some pitfalls, if you use file names with spaces or the like. I added another version, which works with Knuth TeX and gives you control after the file is input without `\everyeof`. You can also nest it.